# Collapsable and non-collapsable menu in Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to make an application using Android Studio. So, what I want is something like this

Output I want:

[image]

And here's my code:

**list_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="2dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/iconimage"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:id="@+id/submenu"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**list_submenu.xml**

```
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:id="@+id/submenu"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.mokui.hopeful;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

View view_Group;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
ExpandableListAdapter mMenuAdapter;
ExpandableListView expandableList;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;


// icons
static int[] icon = {R.drawable.home, R.drawable.write};


@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        expandableList.setIndicatorBounds(expandableList.getRight()- 80, expandableList.getWidth());
    } else {
        expandableList.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(expandableList.getRight()- 80, expandableList.getWidth());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    expandableList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.navigationmenu);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);


   /* ------------------------------EXPAND EXTENSION --------------------------------- */

    if (navigationView != null) {
        setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
    }

    prepareListData();
    mMenuAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expandableList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);

    expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView,
                                    View view,
                                    int groupPosition,
                                    int childPosition, long id) {
            //Log.d("DEBUG", "submenu item clicked");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Header: "+String.valueOf(groupPosition) +
                            "\nItem: "+ String.valueOf(childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            view.setSelected(true);
            if (view_Group != null) {
                view_Group.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            }
            view_Group = view;
            view_Group.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DDDDDD"));
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return false;
        }
    });
    expandableList.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //Log.d("DEBUG", "heading clicked");
            return false;
        }
    });

    /* ------------------------------EXPAND EXTENSION --------------------------------- */
}

private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();


    // Adding data header
    listDataHeader.add("Main Map");
    listDataHeader.add("Create Post");
    listDataHeader.add("Statistics");
    listDataHeader.add("");
    listDataHeader.add("Edit Account");
    listDataHeader.add("Logout");
   // listDataHeader.add("menu3");



    // Adding child data
    List<String> heading1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> heading2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> heading3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    heading3.add("HeatMap and Graphs");
    List<String> heading4 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> heading5 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> heading6 = new ArrayList<String>();




    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), heading1);// Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), heading2);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), heading3);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), heading4);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), heading5);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(5), heading6);


} /* ---------------------------------------- */

private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    /*
    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    } */

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

**ExpandableListAdapter.xml**

```
package com.example.mokui.hopeful;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> mListDataHeader; // header titles

    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> mListDataChild;
    ExpandableListView expandList;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context,
                                 List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String,
                                         List<String>> listChildData
                                 //        ,ExpandableListView mView
    )
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mListDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this.mListDataChild = listChildData;
        //this.expandList = mView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        int i = mListDataHeader.size();
        //Log.d("GROUPCOUNT", String.valueOf(i));
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this.mListDataChild.get(
                this.mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        //Log.d("CHILD", mListDataChild.get(this.mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
        //        .get(childPosition).toString());
        return this.mListDataChild.get(
                this.mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
        }
        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.submenu);
        ImageView headerIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconimage);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
        //lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle.getIconName());
      //  headerIcon.setImageResource(MainActivity.icon[groupPosition]);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_submenu, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.submenu);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But so far this is what I got: My current output result:

[image]

I just want the Statistics Option to be the only one that collapses. But mine turns out that everything is collapsable.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you...

You can use Linearlayout and provide animation to that linearlayout.

To expand the section, You just have to call this method inside your Statistics Option click listener :

```
 llHidden.measure(MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY); // llHidden is the layout which will be GONE as visibility initially, later it will be visible inside Statistics Option.
 expand1(llHidden, llHidden.getMeasuredHeight());
```

To collapse the section, You just have to call this method inside your Statistics Option click listener :

```
 collapse1(llHidden);


 /**
     * To expand any view with smooth animation
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static void expand1(final View v, final int height) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            v.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height);
            final int targtetHeight = height;
            v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Animation a = new Animation() {
                @Override
                protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                    v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1 ? height
                            : (int) (targtetHeight * interpolatedTime);
                    v.requestLayout();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                    return false;
                }
            };
            a.setDuration((int) (targtetHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
            v.startAnimation(a);
        } else {
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            v.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
            ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(0, v.getMeasuredHeight(), v);
            mAnimator.start();
        }
    }



   /**
 * To Collapse any view with smooth animation
 */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static void collapse1(final View v) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        v.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
        Animation a = new Animation() {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                if (interpolatedTime == 1) {
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int) (initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                    v.requestLayout();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return false;
            }
        };
        a.setDuration((int) (initialHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
        v.startAnimation(a);
    } else {
        int finalHeight = v.getHeight();
        ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(finalHeight, 0, v);
        mAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            }
        });
        mAnimator.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: do I put this on the MainActivity.java?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still confuse. Let me get this straight.. So I make a linear layout inside the activity_menu_drawer.xml? so I only need a linear layout for the statisctics?and apply the code you provided?
I'm using the deafault navigation drawer in android studio